# Align items of one WPF ListView to positions relative to final layout of items in another ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

Based on comments, I thought of a way to simplify my question:  an arbitrary point nested inside a user control in the right hand column will end up at some final location after layout and rendering.  I want to find out what that point was and adjust the height of an element on the left hand column so that it ends on that Y coordinate.  I want to repeat that process for all the boxes.

I made a WPF window for displaying decoded serial data.  I have a left hand column with blocks for bytes, and a right hand column with blocks for bit fields.  The bit fields may be one to sixteen bits long, and are not necessarily aligned with byte boundaries.  However I would like the byte column and the bit-fields column to stay in sync.

I've solved the problem of scrolling them together.  I put two list views in a single scroll panel to achieve the effect I want.

The task I need help with is calculating the height to assign each left-hand (byte-)block so that the transitions between byte-blocks line up with the appropriate bits (first red arrow) and so that the overall length comes out correct (second red arrow).  (Note: I picked numbers at random but the intention is that the right hand column displays the bits that are in the bytes of the left hand column - same data different way of displaying that data.  That's why I want the columns to line up.)

[image: Mock up of two column layout.]

The reason it is not a straightforward math calculation is the borders between blocks take up space, so a section with many small bit fields will take up more vertical space than one which consolidates all the bits in fewer fields.  I was able to approximately line things up with complicated code which tracks this and computes `scale*num_bits + offset*num_transitions`, but no value of `scale` and `offset` (determined by trial and error) makes it line up in all cases, and any tweak to the bit-field-box data template would require finding new `scale` and `offset` constants.

Here is the actual data-bound code for the window.  `{Binding Height}` is the computed height for the byte boxes.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="64"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding SerialDataBytes}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8" Height="{Binding Height}" Width="52" Margin="1,1,1,1">
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Value}" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <local:BitDescriptionRow DataContext="{Binding SerialDataFields}" Grid.Column="1">
        </local:BitDescriptionRow>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And here is the code for the user controls in the right hand column. `{Binding Bits}` and `{Binding BorderThickness}` generate the vertical lists of 1's and 0's with a bold divider after every eighth bit.  `{Binding Height}` sets the height of the content of the user control based on number of bits.

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8" Padding="4,4,4,4" Margin="1,1,1,1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="{Binding Height}">
                    <ListView VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Bits}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="Black">
                                        <TextBlock Height="16" Text="{Binding Value}" />
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding FieldValue}" Margin="4,4,4,4" />
                    <TextBlock Width="180" Height="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Ideally I think it would be best if the byte-boxes were dynamically (layout-time) synced somehow where the red arrows are in the example mock up.  It's OK if this requires a two-step layout (flicker).  In the real (not mock up) version I'm using MVVM and databinding.  The height of the byte block is a databound property, so I'm envisioning the laid-out height / laid-out position of the bit-fields coming to the view models via databinding as well.

Examples I've turned up all involve iterating over the UIElements directly, and I'm open to that being the better way.  But if I went that route how would I know which UIElement goes with which view model given that it's dynamic via databound list not a static layout?

Answers to anticipated comments:

- Why not make the byte-blocks a fixed size?

  - That was my first idea, but I like this layout better.  In this application, the bit fields contain the important items and the byte blocks are just informational.  If byte blocks had a fixed height, 1-bit fields would be scrunched up and longer bit fields would use more space than necessary.
- Why not use a DataGrid?

  - Difficult when the rectangles in left and right columns end on different lines.  One could imagine treating the grid and borders as a tileset as 2D games do and generate `|` `-` `L` etc. as needed.  Aside from being horribly complicated this sort of works (I tried it) but when you hit the description-label that throws a monkey-wrench:  the multi-line text should cross multiple datagrid rows.  I couldn't understand how the merge-cells feature works with databinding.  And if you're tiling border elements (`|` `-` `L`) and fighting the datagrid might as well at that point just use a canvas.
- Why not use a Grid?

  - I couldn't find a good example of using a Grid with data bound elements and anyway some of the objections to DataGrid apply to Grid as well.
- Why not use Canvas or draw graphically?

  - I wanted to be able to use regular WPF elements (ListView, Border, etc.) with flow and margins rather than drawing lines manually, and either way you'd still have to calculate effective offsets.

Comment: Maybe you can do something with Grouping? There is the Group 0x40, 0x7a. There is also the groups 0-5 and 6-8. It is mostly a graphic side thing, so I would bet you can solve it largely in the View.

Comment: How does the Group know to ensure the place where 0x40 transitions to 0x7a should line up with the bold bar between bits 7-8 in the second column?

Comment: The left column is bytes captured from the serial port, the right column is interpretation of the bits in those bytes according to a data format.  Since it was an example for layout I didn't take the trouble of making sure the bits in the example match the bytes listed, but the intention is it's the same data.

Comment: I'm trying to understand from your picture how you decided the height of the 40 and 7a to begin with.

Comment: The bold bar on the right of the first red arrow is the transition between the 8th and 9th bits which is the same as the transition between the 1st and 2nd byte in the stream.

Comment: ok, so if the data is supposed to be the same, why not use a usercontrol for column 2 and use an itemtemplate to handle this.

Comment: Indeed I am. The problem is I need to know the final layout position ended up on by an arbitrary point inside that user control in order to make the item in column 1 land on the same point.

Comment: I have problems to understand your goal. Why don't you put both columns inside a `Grid` of single `ListView` item. If you wish to scroll them together why not use only one `ListView`? An why don't you want the left column to stretch to align with the actual byte blocks of the right column?

Comment: You can use a main `ListView` for the whole control. Each `ListViewItem` consists of a `Grid` having two columns and a single row: left column only has a centered `TextBlock`. The right column another `ListView` which has eight items consisting of a horizontal `StackPanel` that hosts two `TextBlocks`: one for the bit value and one for the description.

Comment: What is the word length, two bytes? In this case two bytes would make one item and the hosting panel would be a `Grid` with two rows and two columns. Each row has a `ListView` that can display eight bit. Left column: each row has a centered `TextBlock` to display the hex value. The right column (each row): contains a `ListView` to show  groups of bits. So each `ListViewItem` represents a group of bits. A bit group consists of a horizontal `StackPanel` which hosts a third `ListView` (with a `TextBlock` for the bit value as item template) and a `TextBlock` for the description of the bit group.

Comment: Then use a flag (in the data model) that signals overlapping bit groups. If the last bit group is overlapping (last bit > 8 bit) than hide the lower item border and of the next item (group) hide the top border. Each item can therefore display 8 bits. But visually it will look like they are a single item.

Comment: Example: The group is 10 bit long. Therefore the group model has the overlap flag set. The trigger of this item hides the lower border. The next item (bit group) triggers on previous data and sees the overlap flag is set and hides the top border. It will look like a single block to the user that is perfectly aligned with the byte representation in the first column.

Comment: BionicCode you might consider submitting your comment(s) as an answer.